# How to route to queues without knowing their name in advance?

Tags: routes, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm trying to figure out, if it is possible to use some default routing scheme / exchange in RabbitMQ to achieve the following:

I have some basic hierarchy of devices and groups of devices where a device always belongs to one group.

```
group_a
  device_1  (queue: group_a.device_1)
  device_2  (queue: group_a.device_2)
```

Ideally, I'd like to a have a producer for each group (e.g. `group_a`) that keeps the connection and channel open. Then, when a message needs to be published to a device (e.g. `device_1`) of that group, the producer will send the message to a predefined exchange with the device name as routing key. The exchange will use the routing key as the queue name and put the message in that queue.

The tricky part is: New devices (e.g. `device_3`) may appear during the lifetime of the producer. Thus, I cannot bind routing keys to queue named after the device in advance.

One thing to solve that would be creating the queue and the binding every time a message needs to be delivered manually on-demand which sounds like a bit of overhead to me.

The second solution might me passing the information about a new device to the producer which then adds a new binding.

But maybe, there is an easier way using some kind of dynamic routing that will create queue automatically on-demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it an option for you, you can publish messages to default exchange (nameless) with the routing key equal to queue it designated for.

From the official [RabbitMQ tuttorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-default):

> The default exchange is a direct exchange with no name (empty string)
>   pre-declared by the broker. It has one special property that makes it
>   very useful for simple applications: every queue that is created is
>   automatically bound to it with a routing key which is the same as the
>   queue name.

Comment: That sounds good. One thing, that I don't see in the documentation is, what happens if I use a routing key where the queue does not exist. Do I get an error/nak when I synchronously send the message or is it silently discarded?

Comment: Unless you setup (Alternative Exchange)[http://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html] messages that has no recipients will be silently dropped.